# Mockito - Spying on more than one dependency

Tags: java, mockito

Is it possible to inject a spy for two dependencies into the tested class?
I have this class:

```java
@Service
@Singleton
@MessageReceiver
public class LinkHitCallbackEventHandler {
    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Inject
    private CallbackInvocationBuilder callbackInvocationBuilder;

    @Inject
    private CallbackLogBuilder callbackLogBuilder;

    @MessageReceiver
    public void handle(@SubscribeTo LinkHitEvent event) {
        Entity<Form> entity = EntityFormFactory.createFromEvent(event);

        this.callbackLogBuilder.build(entity);

        Response response = this.callbackInvocationBuilder.post(entity);
    }
}
```

Importantly, it's a simple class with two injected dependencies: **callbackInvocationBuilder** and **callbackLogBuilder**.

I test calls to these dependencies in the following way:

```java
    @Test
    public void send_callback_after_event_is_published() {
        target("/testY")
                .property("jersey.config.client.followRedirects", false)
                .request()
                .header("User-Agent", UserAgentMother.allowedUserAagent())
                .get();

        verify(callbackInvocationBuilder).post(anyObject());
//        verify(callbackLogBuilder).build(anyObject());
    }
```

This arrangement the test passes, because I first call `callbackLogBuilder.build(entity)`.

If I swap calls and call them first `callbackInvocationBuilder.post(entity)`, the test will fail.

Both callbackLogBuilder and callbackInvocationBuilder are spies. I configure them in configure () from JerseyTest. In exactly the same way.

Comment: How do you inject them?

Comment: org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.configure ()
Despite all this, all your questions / answers suggested that my problem should not have happened. Once again, it turned out that the test was correct and detected an error in the tested code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the method to inject spy to use `whitebox` and use verify

like this:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(ClassToTest.class, "Object", spy1);
```

, So the test method ill be like this:

```
    @Test
    public void send_callback_after_event_is_published() {
        Whitebox.setInternalState(LinkHitCallbackEventHandler.class, "callbackInvocationBuilder", spy1);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(LinkHitCallbackEventHandler.class, "callbackInvocationBuilder", spy2);

        target("/testY")
                .property("jersey.config.client.followRedirects", false)
                .request()
                .header("User-Agent", UserAgentMother.allowedUserAagent())
                .get();

        verify(callbackInvocationBuilder).post(anyObject());
        verify(callbackLogBuilder).build(anyObject());
    }
```

, If you want to capture the argument

```
ArgumentCaptor<Entity> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Entity.class);
verify(callbackInvocationBuilder, times(1)).post(captor.capture());

Entity actualEntity = captor.getValue();
assertEquals(expected, actualEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, although I didn't use them, they helped me find the real problem.